# php and mysqli help needed

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, mysqli

it my be SIMPLE but I wonder how I can get my ID with the company name.
I've got that all name comes up but not the ID. I only get the last ID that is in the list
What can I do ?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","****");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }   

        // hent fra db: SELECT ... FROM tabell ORDER BY sted, brukernavn
$sql="SELECT * FROM fotograf ORDER BY sted, firma ";
$data = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$sortedData = [];

// organiser 
foreach ($data as $d)
{
    $place = $d['sted'];
    $id = $d['id'];
    $sortedData[$place][] = $d['firma'];
}

// output
foreach ($sortedData as $place => $userNames)
{
    echo '<h3>' . $place . '</h3>';

    foreach ($userNames as $userName)
    {
        echo '<div><p><a href="fotograf.php?id='. $id .'"><strong>' . $userName . ' </strong></a></div>';
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: So `$d['firma']` is the username?

Comment: yes it is the username and sted is place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting multiple rows back and storing your id in one variable that gets overwritten every loop.

I would recommend you create a class (if u are going the OO way) and add that to the list instead

```
$sortedData = [];

class Fotograf {
    public $Id;
    public $Firma;
}

// organiser 
foreach ($data as $d)
{
    $obj = new Fotograf();
    $obj->Id = $d['id'];
    $obj->Firma = $d['firma'];
    $sortedData[$d['sted']][] = $obj;   
}
```

From there you can access the object itself and now have the Id variable together with the Place variable. Now access it as such:

```
// output
foreach ($sortedData as $place => $userNames)
{
    echo '<h3>' . $place . '</h3>';

    foreach ($userNames as $userName)
    {

        echo '<div><p><a href="fotograf.php?id='. $userName->Id .'"><strong>' . $userName->Firma . ' </strong></a></div>';
    }

}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: id in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/2017/mrfl/test.php on line 38

Catchable fatal error: Object of class Fotograf could not be converted to string in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/2017/mrfl/test.php on line 38

Comment: yes, you cannot use the object as a string later on. you need to access the objects variable. updated my answer to reflect how to access the variables.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code :

```
foreach ($data as $d)
{
 $place = $d['sted'];
 //$id = $d['id']; this is unused variable
 $sortedData[$place] = array("username" => $d['firma'],"id"=>$d['id']);
}

// output
foreach ($sortedData as $place => $userNames)
{
  echo '<h3>' . $place . '</h3>';

  foreach ($userNames as $userName)
  {
    echo '<div><p><a href="fotograf.php?id='. $userName["id"] .'"><strong>' . $userName["username"] . ' </strong></a></div>';
  }

}
```

Comment: i got this error 
Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/2017/mrfl/test.php on line 32

Warning: Illegal string offset 'firma' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/2017/mrfl/test.php on line 32 2`